# Overwrite or surpress Mixed content message originated by browser with JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, https, mixed-content

I am taking care of a website, which is setup with https, but running into the "mixed content problem".

My question is: Is there a chance to get "rid" of this by using some JavaScript/JQuery?

Note: I am pretty much aware that this is only a *third*-best-solution. So please no comments on the idea itself.

Comment: Joey, be free to add some comments or questions if you want. If there is nothing else you can mark the answer as accepted since it is the only possible reaction and correct reaction you will get.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one solution to get rid of mixed content warnings thrown by the browser: don't have mixed content. It is a security warning. It is there for a reason. It would be a security issue to have the possiblity to surpress the error with javascript/jquery or something else.

So: **no you can't overwrite or supress these warnings by javascript/jquery or any other tooling,library or framework as it would be considered "dangerous"**

Maybe you can surpress them with some browser settings but that's not adviced.

[Firefox about mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Security/MixedContent/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

[Chrome about mixed content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content)

[Microsoft about mixed content](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2625928)